# c# Webbrowser How to select an added dom element (form hidden button) and invoke a click on the button

Tags: c#, forms, webbrowser-control

Simply,

I am trying to add a form tag, with a hidden and a submit button to a web page loaded in a webbrowser in c#. After I add it I want to invoke the click event on the button.

I do not have a lot of code to show as I was unable to even get close. I could not find an example of this in google.

I have tried to use create element, then InsertAdjacentElement, which seems to work when I examine HtmlDoc, but when i try to get the element by ID it always returns null.

```
System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument doc = harvester.Document;

string ftm = "<form Id = 'SD' method='POST' action='day.cfm'><input type='hidden' name='Day' value='" + selDay + "'><input id='SubmitDay' type='submit' value='View the Schedule'></form>";
var divElem = doc.CreateElement("div");
divElem.InnerText = ftm;
divElem = doc.Body.InsertAdjacentElement(HtmlElementInsertionOrientation.AfterBegin, divElem);

HtmlElement button = doc.GetElementById("SubmitDay");
// button = null, always.
```

Thanks for any help.

[image]

Image shows the DOM after inserting the form.

So here is the code working... 
FYI: selDay and wordDay are just string vars containing dates

```
System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument doc = harvester.Document;
const string quote = "\"";
string ftm = "<form Id = 'SD' method='POST' action='schedule.cfm'><input type='hidden' name='Day' value=" + quote + selDay + quote+ ">" + wordDay + "<input id='SubmitDay' type='submit' value='View the Schedule'></form>";
var divElem = doc.CreateElement("div");
divElem.InnerHtml = ftm;
divElem = doc.Body.InsertAdjacentElement(HtmlElementInsertionOrientation.AfterBegin, divElem);

HtmlElement button = doc.GetElementById("SubmitDay");
button.InvokeMember("click");
```

Comment: Is there a reason for all the trickery instead of just submitting the form from javascript without the hidden submit button?

Comment: Won't `divElem.InnerText = ftm` escape your HTML anyway (I could be wrong...)

Comment: The trickery is not malicious, it is to automate a browser based system (old and terrible) in a winforms application. What I am trying to do is harvest schedule details for the employee that can then be referenced in the winforms application, where it can be handled better and other required tasks can be automated. In short i am taking a process that had about 15 steps and reducing it to just 2 or 3.

Comment: wgraham - The innerTEXT looks correct after adding it. I have not yet gotten to the point of testing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the screenshot, you are attempting to inject HTML into the page by setting the `InnerText` property. From the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.innertext(v=vs.110).aspx) for this property:

> If you attempt to assign HTML to an element with InnerText, the HTML code will display as literals in the document, just as if you were viewing HTML within a text file.

This means that your `form` and `input` elements are being injected into the page *escaped* -- `&lt;form&gt;` instead of `<form>`, so when you search the DOM for the button it doesn't exist.

Try using [`InnerHtml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.innerhtml(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: I suspected I was being a moron :) Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'd handle this problem a bit differently.  Rather than trying to create an HTML document using .NET HtmlElements, I would simply construct a string variable that contains my web page content.  As part of that, I would create a short javascript, that would be triggered when the page is opened (that way you don't need the submit button).

Lastly, after the page is complete, I'd open it a browser object, and it'll do it's thing.

Alternatively, you can use the HttpPost (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.activities.messaging.httppost(v=azure.10).aspx) class to do the same thing (without having to create a web page).

Comment: "I'd handle this problem a bit differently." - Well thats great, but it is not what I was asking. Also your answer will not work for what I am doing, not to mention a lot more work is involved. Thanks but lets try to stay on topic.